# How to use JS and jQuery functions in script tag in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, klarna, klarna-widget

I am trying to integrate Klarna Payments into my Angular site but the examples are provided in plain JS and jQuery, which I am not so familiar with.

What I need to do:
Import Klarna's JS script and call 2 functions within it, Init and Load.
Then on a button click I need to call the Authorize function. There may be multiple buttons and if so there will be a Load and Authorize function for each, this is dynamic. I then need to get the token returned by the Authorize function in order to pass to my backend.

[Here'](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRM7gd-jxCp5C-tylVCX0ZfKWKP_a19M/view)s the example provided by Klarna:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://x.klarnacdn.net/kp/lib/v1/api.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
//The following method initializes the Klarna Payments JS library
    window.klarnaAsyncCallback = function () {
        Klarna.Payments.init({ 
            client_token: ''
        });
        console.log("Payments initialized");
//The following method loads the payment_method_category in the container with the id of 'klarna_container'
        Klarna.Payments.load({
        container: '#klarna_container',
            payment_method_category: ''
            
        }, function (res) {
               console.log("Load function called")
                console.debug(res);
        });
    };


/*The following is the authorize function, which triggers Klarna to perform a risk assessment of the purchase 
  The successful response of this risk assessment is an authorization token, which in this example is logged in the console
*/
  $(function(){
    $("button.authorize").on('click', function(){
        Klarna.Payments.authorize({
            payment_method_category: ''
            }, {
              billing_address: {
                given_name: "Jane",
                family_name: "Doe",
                email: "jane@doe.com",
                title: "Ms",
                street_address: "512 City Park Ave",
                postal_code: "43215",
                city: "Columbus",
                region: "oh",
                phone: "6142607295",
                country: "US"
              },
              order_amount: 20000,
              order_tax_amount: 0,
              order_lines: [{
                type : "physical",
                reference : "19-402",
                name : "black T-Shirt",
                quantity : 2,
                unit_price : 5000,
                tax_rate : 0,
                total_amount : 10000,
                total_discount_amount : 0,
                total_tax_amount : 0
            },
            {
            type : "physical",
            reference : "19-402",
            name : "red trousers",
            quantity : 1,
            unit_price : 10000,
            tax_rate : 0,
            total_amount : 10000,
            total_discount_amount : 0,
            total_tax_amount : 0
            }],
             }, function(res) {
                console.log("Response from the authorize call:")
                console.log(res)
              
            })
    })
  })
</script>


<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; padding-top: 150px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <img src="https://x.klarnacdn.net/payment-method/assets/badges/generic/klarna.svg" style="width: 500px; margin: auto;"> 
</div>

<!--Klarna container-->
<div id="klarna_container" style="width: 500px; margin: auto;"></div>
<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto;">
    <!--Button to trigger authorize call-->
    <button class="authorize" style="width: 500px; height: 50px; margin: auto;">Your Buy Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's what I've tried so far (all on one component for now while testing. Will be split into services or whatever once it's working)

test.component.html

```
<p>testing...</p>

<div class="klarna-widget">
  <div id="klarna-payments-container" style="width: 500px; margin: auto;">
    <!-- In future there will be multiples of this div & contents with different IDs -->

    <div style="width: 500px; margin: auto;">
      <!--Button to trigger authorize call-->
      <button class="authorize" style="width: 500px; height: 50px; margin: auto;">Your Buy Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

test.component.ts

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { KlarnaSession } from 'src/app/payment/KlarnaObjects';
import { GlobalConstants } from 'src/app/shared/global-constants';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
declare let Klarna: Function;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  klarnaSession: KlarnaSession;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http.get<KlarnaSession>(`${GlobalConstants.apiUrl}/Payment/GetKlarnaSession`).subscribe(
      (result: KlarnaSession) => {
        this.loadKlarnaSDK(result);
      }
    );
  }

  loadKlarnaSDK(session: KlarnaSession) {
    const scriptjq = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    scriptjq.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, scriptjq);

    const script1 = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script1.src = 'https://x.klarnacdn.net/kp/lib/v1/api.js';
    script1.async = true;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, script1);

    const script2 = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script2.text = `window.klarnaAsyncCallback = function () {
      Klarna.Payments.init({
        client_token: '${session.client_token}'
      });

      // In the real thing, I'll need to call this for each item in session.payment_method_categories[].
      // Same for the authorize function.
      Klarna.Payments.load({
        container: 'klarna-payments-container',
        payment_method_category: '${session.payment_method_categories[0].identifier}'
      }, function (res) {
        console.log('Load function called');
        console.debug(res);
      });
    };`;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, script2);
  }

}
```

The `Klarna.Payments.load` doesn't work, before even trying the authorize. I'm not even sure if the Init is being called.

Console gives this error:

> Uncaught InvalidContainerSelectorError: The container selector is invalid. Please, check that the used ID or CSS class name is correct and that it targets an existing DOM element.

even though the container name `klarna-payments-container` is definitely correct.

How should this be done in Angular? Am I on the wrong track completely?

---

After sorting the selector problem there is still an issue with it recognising the authorize function.

Updated ts file:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { KlarnaSession } from 'src/app/payment/KlarnaObjects';
import { GlobalConstants } from 'src/app/shared/global-constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  klarnaSession: KlarnaSession;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http.get<KlarnaSession>(`${GlobalConstants.apiUrl}/Payment/GetKlarnaSession`).subscribe(
      (result: KlarnaSession) => {
        this.loadKlarnaSDK(result);
      }
    );
  }

  loadKlarnaSDK(session: KlarnaSession) {
    const scriptjq = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    scriptjq.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, scriptjq);

    const script1 = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script1.src = 'https://x.klarnacdn.net/kp/lib/v1/api.js';
    script1.async = true;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, script1);

    const script2 = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script2.text = `window.klarnaAsyncCallback = function () {
      Klarna.Payments.init({
        client_token: '${session.client_token}'
      });

      Klarna.Payments.load({
        container: '#klarna-payments-container',
        payment_method_category: '${session.payment_method_categories[0].identifier}'
      }, function (res) {
        console.log('Load function called');
        console.debug(res);
      });
    };

    $(function() {
      $("button.authorize").on('click', function() {
        Klarna.Payments.authorize({
          payment_method_category: '${session.payment_method_categories[0].identifier}'
        }, {
          // ORDER DETAILS GO HERE
        }, function(res) {
          console.log("Response from the authorize call:")
          console.log(res)
        })
      })

    })`;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, script2);
  }

}
```

It complains about the first line `$(function() {...`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: The error message says the word _selector_, so I would try to actually turn that into a valid CSS selector. Looking at the html that you included, `klarna-payments-container` is an id, so the selector for that would be `#klarna-payments-container`. Try using this one instead, with a hashbang prefix.

Comment: Doh, thank you, that sorted the load. However it's still not working at the next step, see the updated question.

Comment: Does the jQuery script load? You can look in the console for errors, or better yet in the network tab, to see if the `jquery.min.js` file is being pulled in.

Comment: That looks fine in the network tab. No console errors apart from this one.